# How can I create a new activity in a HiltViewModel - Jetpack compose?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Currently I am building an Android application using Jetpack compose library with Firebase. I'm rebuilding the app based on this sample builder [Make it so android](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/make-it-so-android)

I am stuck not knowing what to do so that after successful login account confirmation in LoginViewModel (fun onSignInClick), how can I forward to MainActivity.kt file. Is this the right solution? Because I just learned recently.

1. Class LoginModelView

```
package com.tnmd.learningenglishapp.screens.login


@HiltViewModel
class LoginViewModel @Inject constructor(
  private val accountService: AccountService,
  logService: LogService
) : LearningEnglishAppViewModel(logService) {
  var uiState = mutableStateOf(LoginUiState())
    private set

  private val email
    get() = uiState.value.email
  private val password
    get() = uiState.value.password

  private val _loginEvent = MutableSharedFlow<LogInEvent>()
  val loginEvent = _loginEvent.asSharedFlow()

  fun onEmailChange(newValue: String) {
    uiState.value = uiState.value.copy(email = newValue)
  }

  fun onPasswordChange(newValue: String) {
    uiState.value = uiState.value.copy(password = newValue)
  }

  fun onSignInClick(openAndPopUp: (String, String) -> Unit) {
    if (!email.isValidEmail()) {
      SnackbarManager.showMessage(AppText.email_error)
      return
    }

    if (password.isBlank()) {
      SnackbarManager.showMessage(AppText.empty_password_error)
      return
    }

    launchCatching {
      if( accountService.authenticate(email, password)){
       //I try to start a Activity in there
        val intent = Intent(this@LoginViewModel, MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
      }else{
        openAndPopUp(SETTINGS_SCREEN, LOGIN_SCREEN)
      }
    }
  }

  fun onForgotPasswordClick() {
    if (!email.isValidEmail()) {
      SnackbarManager.showMessage(AppText.email_error)
      return
    }

    launchCatching {
      accountService.sendRecoveryEmail(email)
      SnackbarManager.showMessage(AppText.recovery_email_sent)
    }
  }

  sealed class LogInEvent {
    data class ErrorLogIn(val errorLogIn: String): LogInEvent()
    object Succes : LogInEvent()
  }
}
```

2. LoginScreen.kt

```
package com.tnmd.learningenglishapp.screens.login


@Composable
fun LoginScreen(
  openAndPopUp: (String, String) -> Unit,
  modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
  viewModel: LoginViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
  val uiState by viewModel.uiState

  BasicToolbar(AppText.login_details)

  Column(
    modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth().fillMaxHeight().verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
  ) {
    EmailField(uiState.email, viewModel::onEmailChange, Modifier.fieldModifier())
    PasswordField(uiState.password, viewModel::onPasswordChange, Modifier.fieldModifier())

    BasicButton(AppText.sign_in, Modifier.basicButton()) { viewModel.onSignInClick(openAndPopUp) }

    BasicTextButton(AppText.forgot_password, Modifier.textButton()) {
      viewModel.onForgotPasswordClick()
    }
  }
}
```

3. LoginController.kt

```
package com.tnmd.learningenglishapp




@Composable
@ExperimentalMaterialApi
fun LoginController() {
    LearningEnglishAppTheme() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
            RequestNotificationPermissionDialog()
        }

        Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
            val appState = rememberLoginState()

            Scaffold(
                snackbarHost = {
                    SnackbarHost(
                        hostState = it,
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
                        snackbar = { snackbarData ->
                            Snackbar(snackbarData, contentColor = MaterialTheme.colors.onPrimary)
                        }
                    )
                },
                scaffoldState = appState.scaffoldState,
            ) { innerPaddingModifier ->
                NavHost(
                    navController = appState.navController,
                    startDestination = SETTINGS_SCREEN,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPaddingModifier)
                ) {
                    loginGraph(appState)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
@OptIn(ExperimentalPermissionsApi::class)
@Composable
fun RequestNotificationPermissionDialog() {
    val permissionState = rememberPermissionState(permission = Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)

    if (!permissionState.status.isGranted) {
        if (permissionState.status.shouldShowRationale) RationaleDialog()
        else PermissionDialog { permissionState.launchPermissionRequest() }
    }
}

@Composable
fun rememberLoginState(
    scaffoldState: ScaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState(),
    navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController(),
    snackbarManager: SnackbarManager = SnackbarManager,
    resources: Resources = resourcesLogin(),
    coroutineScope: CoroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
) =
    remember(scaffoldState, navController, snackbarManager, resources, coroutineScope) {
        LearningEnglishAppState(scaffoldState, navController, snackbarManager, resources, coroutineScope)
    }

@Composable
@ReadOnlyComposable
fun resourcesLogin(): Resources {
    LocalConfiguration.current
    return LocalContext.current.resources
}

@ExperimentalMaterialApi
fun NavGraphBuilder.loginGraph(appState: LearningEnglishAppState) {
    composable(SPLASH_SCREEN) {
        SplashScreen(openAndPopUp = { route, popUp -> appState.navigateAndPopUp(route, popUp) })
    }

    composable(LOGIN_SCREEN) {
        LoginScreen(openAndPopUp = { route, popUp -> appState.navigateAndPopUp(route, popUp) })
    }

    composable(SIGN_UP_SCREEN) {
        SignUpScreen(openAndPopUp = { route, popUp -> appState.navigateAndPopUp(route, popUp) })
    }

    composable(SETTINGS_SCREEN) {
        SettingsScreen(
            restartApp = { route -> appState.clearAndNavigate(route) },
            openScreen = { route -> appState.navigate(route) }
        )
    }

}
```

4. LoginActivity

```
package com.tnmd.learningenglishapp.activity


@AndroidEntryPoint
@ExperimentalMaterialApi
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            LoginController()
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: This is not how you supposed to use compose and viewmodels. A simple way to do it is try making your `onSignInClick ` fun in viewModel modify some response or state and in your `loginScreen` observe that state and when it changes to true or something you immediately use the `navController` to navigate to your `homeScreen` or something

Comment: Since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-make-a-clean-architecture-android-app-using-mvvm-firestore-and-jetpack-compose-abdb5e02a2d8) will also help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreCleanArchitectureApp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the help of Ayman Ait, now it worked, this is my code after fixing:

1. LoginViewModel (In this file, I created a login event to LoginScreen can get it to change Activity)

```html
package com.tnmd.learningenglishapp.screens.login


@HiltViewModel
class LoginViewModel @Inject constructor(
  private val accountService: AccountService,
  logService: LogService
) : LearningEnglishAppViewModel(logService) {
  var uiState = mutableStateOf(LoginUiState())
    private set

  private val email
    get() = uiState.value.email
  private val password
    get() = uiState.value.password

  private val _loginEvent = MutableSharedFlow<LogInEvent>()
  val loginEvent = _loginEvent.asSharedFlow()

  fun onEmailChange(newValue: String) {
    uiState.value = uiState.value.copy(email = newValue)
  }

  fun onPasswordChange(newValue: String) {
    uiState.value = uiState.value.copy(password = newValue)
  }

  fun onSignInClick(openAndPopUp: (String, String) -> Unit) {
    if (!email.isValidEmail()) {
      SnackbarManager.showMessage(AppText.email_error)
      return
    }

    if (password.isBlank()) {
      SnackbarManager.showMessage(AppText.empty_password_error)
      return
    }

    launchCatching {
      if( accountService.authenticate(email, password) == true){
        _loginEvent.emit(LogInEvent.Success)
      }else{
        openAndPopUp(SETTINGS_SCREEN, LOGIN_SCREEN)
      }
    }
  }

  fun onForgotPasswordClick() {
    if (!email.isValidEmail()) {
      SnackbarManager.showMessage(AppText.email_error)
      return
    }

    launchCatching {
      accountService.sendRecoveryEmail(email)
      SnackbarManager.showMessage(AppText.recovery_email_sent)
    }
  }

  sealed class LogInEvent {
    data class ErrorLogIn(val errorLogIn: String): LogInEvent()
    object Success : LogInEvent()
  }
}
```

2. LoginScreen.kt

```html
package com.tnmd.learningenglishapp.screens.login

@Composable
fun LoginScreen(
  openAndPopUp: (String, String) -> Unit,
  modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
  viewModel: LoginViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
  val uiState by viewModel.uiState

  val context = LocalContext.current

  // Collect events from the loginEvent flow
  @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
  LaunchedEffect(viewModel.loginEvent) {
    viewModel.loginEvent.collect { event ->
      when (event) {
        is LoginViewModel.LogInEvent.Success -> {
          val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
          context.startActivity(intent)
        }
        is LoginViewModel.LogInEvent.ErrorLogIn -> {
        }
      }
    }
  }

  BasicToolbar(AppText.login_details)

  Column(
    modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth().fillMaxHeight().verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
  ) {
    EmailField(uiState.email, viewModel::onEmailChange, Modifier.fieldModifier())
    PasswordField(uiState.password, viewModel::onPasswordChange, Modifier.fieldModifier())

    BasicButton(AppText.sign_in, Modifier.basicButton()) { viewModel.onSignInClick(openAndPopUp) }

    BasicTextButton(AppText.forgot_password, Modifier.textButton()) {
      viewModel.onForgotPasswordClick()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).